# ModuleNotFoundError when importing package, tried using __init__

Tags: python, module, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to access functions in preprocess.py from preprocess_test.py. In preprocess_test.py, I'm importing functions from preprocess.py by writing `from main.preprocess import *` However, when running preprocess_test.py, I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'` I believe I put the `__init__.py` files in the correct folders. Do you know why this error is occurring? Thank you.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
src/                          
      __init__.py              
      main/                  
              __init__.py
              preprocess.py
              ...
      tst/                  
              __init__.py
              preprocess_test.py
```

Comment: How are you running `preprocess_test.py`? It apparently does not have `src` in its list of directories in which to find modules.

Comment: From the src folder, I am running `python3 preprocess_test.py`, which triggers the main method.

Comment: If `src` is the current working directory, then `python3 preprocess_test.py` should result in a file-not-found error, because `preprocess_test.py` is in `src/test`, not `src` itself. If `src/tst` is the current working directory, then `src` is not on your module search path.

Comment: My bad, I meant that I am running `python3 tst/preprocess_test.py` from the src folder. I also tried running `python3 preprocess_test.py` from the tst folder, but that resulted in the same error.

Comment: Yes: the problem is that `src` is not on your module search path, not that `src` is not a valid package. You can try `PYTHONPATH=. python3 tst/preprocess_test.py`, or you can use a test runner like (I think) `python3 -munittest tst.preprocess_test.py`

Comment: That solved the issue, thank you!